# Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed

Tags: linux, java-8, jdk

Boa noite, estou problemas ao instalar java8 no umbuntu

ja tentei deletar todos apt-get que instalei, e reinstalar.
estou seguindo esse tuto
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-o-java-com-apt-get-no-ubuntu-16-04-pt

cheguei ao ponto de reinstalar o umbuntu, e neste comando

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

da o erro abaixo

```
root@henrique-Aspire-5741:~# apt-get install oracle-java8-installer 
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version (8u201-1~webupd8~1).
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 3 não atualizados.
1 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
Depois desta operação, 0 B adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Você quer continuar? [S/n] 
Configurando oracle-java8-installer (8u201-1~webupd8~1) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2019-04-16 20:27:16--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolvendo download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.52.118.67
Conectando-se a download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.52.118.67|:80... conectado.
A requisição HTTP foi enviada, aguardando resposta... 302 Moved Temporarily
Localização: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz [redirecionando]
--2019-04-16 20:27:16--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolvendo edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.2.191.58, 2600:1419:0:6a1::366, 2600:1419:0:69f::366
Conectando-se a edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.2.191.58|:443... conectado.
A requisição HTTP foi enviada, aguardando resposta... 302 Moved Temporarily
Localização: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555457357_6043b825975efc4efe4e795c46e76390 [redirecionando]
--2019-04-16 20:27:17--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555457357_6043b825975efc4efe4e795c46e76390
Conectando-se a download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.52.118.67|:80... conectado.
A requisição HTTP foi enviada, aguardando resposta... 301 Moved Permanently
Localização: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555457357_6043b825975efc4efe4e795c46e76390 [redirecionando]
--2019-04-16 20:27:17--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555457357_6043b825975efc4efe4e795c46e76390
Conectando-se a download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.52.118.67|:443... conectado.
A requisição HTTP foi enviada, aguardando resposta... 404 Not Found
2019-04-16 20:27:22 ERRO 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 installed oracle-java8-installer package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

uma coisa estranha é que qualquer apt-get que tento instalar da erro Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed. Por exemplo um sudo apt-get install vim

quando dou  um java -version

```
openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.10.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.10.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Tente rodar esses comandos 
`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java8-installer.postinst -f`
`sudo dpkg --configure oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: tentei,sem sucesso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira mais descomplicada de obter o Java (e outras coisas relacionadas ao ecossistema da JVM como Maven, Gradle, Springboot, Kotlin, Scala e etc) em uma distribuição Linux é usando o [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/)

Para realizar a instalação do mesmo, basta digitar:

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Após a instalação:

```
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Feito isso, basta instalar a versão (8,9,10...) desejada do Java (Oracle, Zulu, OpenJDK, Amazon e etc). Para consultar os tipos disponíveis basta digitar

```
sdk list java
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para escolher a versão a ser instalada, basta digitar:

```
sdk install java "versão desejada"
```

Após a instalação, o sdkman irá perguntar se você deseja setar como Default... Você coloca Yes[Y]. Para exportar o JDK para uso em outras IDEs, sugiro criar uma variável JAVA_HOME

```
JAVA_HOME="$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/java/current"
export JAVA_HOME
```

Feito isso, basta reiniciar o shell e usar como desejar:

Comment: Muitíssimo Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente:)

Comment: Marque como resposta caso tenha solucionado seu problema

Answer (score 0):

Parece que o instalador ainda não foi atualizado.
Você pode tentar baixar diretamente do repositório da oracle, tente esses comandos:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u181|JAVA_VERSION=8u191|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1845567095bfbfebd42ed0d09397939796d05456290fb20a83c476ba09f991d3"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="53c29507e2405a7ffdbba627e6d64856089b094867479edc5ede4105c1da0d65"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_181|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_191|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Leia mais sobre em: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686&p=13699352#post13699352

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758465/ubuntu-oracle-jdk-8-is-not-installed

Comment: Tem várias perguntas iguais, a mais completa que encontrei foi essa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587635/dpkg-error-processing-package-oracle-java8-installer-configure

Comment: sim, esse link que postei ja tentei todas as soluções apresentadas porém sem sucesso, acho muito estranho é que os 4 links que ele tenta acessar para download não funcionam, os 3 primeiros dão acesso negado e o ultimo not found, ai tentei baixar manualmente e instalar manualmente, porem da o msm erro ele tenta fazer o download sendo que ja instalei manualmente